# What's the best way to generate a single feed from different models?

Tags: django, feed

In my site, I have three models, organized in two apps, All this models have a `timestamp` field, which defines the order of appearance in the site's feed. Instead of creating a feed for every model and making single queries ordered by the `timestamp` field, I want to generate a single feed that contains all this objects, rendering each one with their corresponding template, and all of them ordered by the `timestamp` attribute.

My first attempt would be listing all objects and combining them in a single list and sort them within Python:

```
class SiteFeed(Feed):
    ...
    def items(self):
        objects = list(model1.objects.all()) + list(model2.objects.all()) + list(model3.objects.all())
        objects.sort(key=lamda obj: obj.timestamp)
        return = objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would return an iterator from the `items` method. in this case sorting and aggregation of objects can be done in a lazy manner. If you pre-sort the three collections of the objects that you want to combine before you construct the iterator, the final sorting is just a matter of choosing the next object from the right collection on each iteration. Do you see what I mean?

for example:

`class SiteFeed(Feed):
    ...
    def items(self):
        i = model1.objects.order_by('timestamp').iterator()
        j = model2.objects.order_by('timestamp').iterator()
        k = model3.objects.order_by('timestamp').iterator()

        try:                  u = i.next()
        except StopIteration: u = None

        try:                  v = j.next()
        except StopIteration: v = None

        try:                  w = k.next()
        except StopIteration: w = None
        ...
        yield min([u,v,w], key=lambda x: x.timestamp if x else datetime.max)
        ...
        # at this point you need to reiterate the iterator
        # corresponding to the variable that you yielded
        # and yield again
        # so, the above code must be in some sort of a loop
        # until ALL iterators are exhausted`

Comment: I'm not used to iterators, could you please provide an example code to ilustrate your answer? I can't see how to build that iterator, but I think I understand the general idea.

Comment: That's a simple iterator. The problem still remains, I need all those objects of diferente models sorted by the common attribute `timestamp`. In that code, only `model1` objects are returned.

Comment: yes, I gave you just an example since you said that you are not used to iterators. I have updated my answer again to give you a better idea about what I mean. Sorry, I have no time to write a complete solution. This is a pseudo code, I have not tested anything.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and get back with comments. Thanks!